# How to center fixed navbar in another div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a fixed and centered navbar div which is within another div that's using a parallax effect. If I set the position to relative, the navbar will be centered within the other div however setting it to fixed will have a fixed navbar but not centered. I would like to avoid using margin left x amount of px because it doesn't seem consistent for cross resolutions. Is there anyway to keep the navbar fixed position but have it centered within the other div without mar?

This is my code:

```css
#page-wrap {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 1366px;
  max-width: 2048px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 95%;
}

header {
  background: url('../images/cover1.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 90%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}

#nav {
  background: #f0f;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  min-width: 980px;
  max-width: 2048px;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 1;
}

#main {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-wrap">
  <header>
    <nav id="nav">Nav</nav>
  </header>
  <div id="main">Lorem ipsum flash.</div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).on('scroll', function(e) {
    $('#nav').css('opacity', ($(document).scrollTop() / 500));
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();

    $('header').css({
      'background-position-y': 0 + (st * .77) + "px"
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could keep your `nav` in center of screen, but you need to wrap it inside fixed container, [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfhsbu2d/2/). HTML is slightly different:

```
<div id="page-wrap">
    <header>
        <div class="nav_container">
            <nav id="nav">Nav</nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="main">Lorem ipsum flash.</div>
</div>
```

In CSS fixed element becomes `.nav_container` and `nav` must become `inline-block` - that way we can use text align:

```
#page-wrap {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 1366px;
    max-width: 2048px;
    margin: 0px auto; 
    width: 95%;
}
header {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/500x500') no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 90%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
.nav_container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav_container nav {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f0f;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 2048px;
    height: 100px;
}
#main {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Or keep the nav as "block" element but set its margin to "auto". This way you dont have to use text-align, cause it will also affect your text inside nav

Comment: It is impossible because he used `min-width`, the width is not fixed, so he cannot use margin `0 auto`.

Comment: Exactly! Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72uandrd/) (resize and scroll to test it). And also, there is no point of using min-width in this case at all... max-width does all the job.

Answer (score 0):

How about centering your **nav** using javascript?

```
$('#nav').css({'left': (($(document).width() - $('#nav').width())/2 )+"px"});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice for what you're trying to do. Let me know if this doesn't work.

```
#nav {
       background: #f0f;
       margin: 0 auto;
       height: 500px;
       min-width: 980px;
       max-width: 2048px;
       position: fixed;
       opacity: 1;
       left: 50%;
    }
```